# somar input no formato time

Tags: javascript, html, input

Tenho 3 `input` o primeiro recebe hora de inicio o segundo hora de saída e o terceiro a subtração entre eles.

```
function calcular(){
    var segent = parseInt(document.getElementById('segent').value, 10);
    var segsai = parseInt(document.getElementById('segsai').value, 10);
    document.getElementById('resultseg').value = segent - segsai;
}
```

preciso calcular entrada - saída, porem com esse código ele retorna valores estranhos como -2, 0, -8...

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece porque a conta está a ser feita ao contrário.

Deveria ser `segsai (hora saída)` que é o valor maior, menos `segent (hora entrada)` que será o valor menor.

```js
var calc = document.getElementById('calcular');
calc.onclick = function(){
    var segent = parseInt(document.getElementById('segent').value, 10);
    var segsai = parseInt(document.getElementById('segsai').value, 10);
    document.getElementById('resultseg').value = segsai - segent;
}
```

```html
<input id="segent" value="09:00" type="time"/>
<input id="segsai" value="17:00" type="time"/>
<input id="resultseg"/>
<button id="calcular">calcular</button>
```